# Is it possible to have 2 conditions within 1 if statement?

Tags: php

I currently have the following line of code

```
elseif($_POST['aspam'] != 'fire'){
print "Is ice really hotter than fire?";
}
```

Is there any sort of OR function within PHP? as if to say if...

```
$_POST['aspam'] != 'fire' OR !='Fire'
```

OR alternatively make my value not case sensitive? 
Hopefully this makes sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `||` or `or` (lowercase) operator.

```
elseif($_POST['aspam'] != 'fire' || $_POST['aspam'] != 'Fire'){
    print "Is ice really hotter than fire?";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure.

```
$_POST['aspam'] != 'fire' or $_POST['aspam'] !='Fire'
```

Just remember that each condition is separate. Saying `or != 'Fire'` doesn't automatically interpret it as `or $_POST['aspam'] != 'Fire'`.

They're called [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

To compare the lowercase:

```
strtolower($_POST['aspam'] != 'fire'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do two conditions like this:

```
if($_POST['aspam'] != 'fire' || $_POST['aspam'] != 'Fire')
```

If I were you in this case, I would do:

```
if(strtolower($_POST['aspam']) != 'fire')
```

Answer (score 2):

A PHP `OR` is created with `||`, `AND` created with `&&`, etc. So your code example would look like:

```
if ( ($_POST['aspam'] != 'fire') || ($_POST['aspam'] != 'Fire') )
```

However in your case it would be better to:

```
if (strtolower($_POST['aspam']) != 'fire')
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different logical operators in PHP.

Use for "OR" two pipes: ||

```
$_POST['aspam'] != 'fire' || !='Fire'
```

Here's a link with all operators:
http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_operators.asp

Comment: **Much** better would be to link to the official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
if (first condition || second condition){
your code
}
```

The OR is represented by 2 pipes - ||

Something more:
You can also have AND:

```
if(first condition && second condition){
Your code...
}
```

So and is represented by &&

Answer (score 1):

This is the logical OR

```
$_POST['aspam'] != 'fire' || !='Fire'
```

and this is the case-insensitive (ToLower function)

```
strtolower($_POST['aspam']) != 'fire'
```

Comment: Thanks @jonathan, can I ask does the strtolower make my value all lowercase therefore no matter how its input it should work?

Comment: @Liam: yes, that's what the strlower function does. So "Fire" or "FIRE" will have an output of "fire".

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtolower($_POST['aspam'] )!='fire'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the checking of your variable case insensitive, you can use below code

```
if(strtolower($_POST['aspam'])!='fire')
   echo "this is matching";
```

Answer (score 1):

> OR alternatively make my value not
>   case sensitive?

```
if (strtolower($_POST['aspam']) != 'fire'){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Try this:

```
elseif($_POST['aspam'] != 'fire' || $_POST['aspam'] != 'Fire')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use case insensitive string comparison:

```
if (strcasecmp($_POST['aspam'], 'fire') !== 0) {
    print "Is ice really hotter than fire?"; 
}
```

Or a list:

```
if (!in_array($_POST['aspam'], array('Fire','fire')) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest option here would probably be [`stristr`](http://php.net/stristr):

```
if (stristr($_POST["aspam"], "FIRE")) {
```

It does a case-insensitive search. To make it a fixed-length match you might however need [`strcasecmp`](http://php.net/strcasecmp) or [`strncasecmp`](http://php.net/strncasecmp) in your case. (However I find that less readable, and doesn't look necessary in your case.)